# The text of underbrace overlaps with the text of document

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am using the underbrace to explain some equations, but the text of the underbrace always overlaps the text of my document. Is there any way to solve this issue?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\Xi}_{p}=\left\lbrace\smash{\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_\text{$p+1$      copies}},\mathbf{\Xi}_{int},\smash{\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_\text{$p+1$ copies}} \right\rbrace,
\end{equation}
onto $\bar{n}$ degrees of freedom, $p-1$th order function space $\bar{\mathcal{N}}_{\bar{n},p-1}=span\left\lbrace{N}_{i,p-1}\right\rbrace$ defined by knot vector:
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: As "span" appears to be a math operator, it should probably be typeset with upright letters instead of math italic letters. Since you're using the `amsmath` package, I recommend you set up `\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}` in the preamble and write `...\span\lbrace{N}_{i,p-1}\rbrace...` in the body of the document.

Answer (score 3):

No need to smash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \mathbf{\Xi}_{p}=\lbrace\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_\text{$p+1$      copies},\mathbf{\Xi}_{int},\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_\text{$p+1$ copies} \rbrace,
    \end{equation}
    onto $\bar{n}$ degrees of freedom, $p-1$th order function space $\bar{\mathcal{N}}_{\bar{n},p-1}=span\left\lbrace{N}_{i,p-1}\right\rbrace$ defined by knot vector:
\end{document}
```

[image]